# If Cartesian product of sets becomes an internal hom in Rel what do functions become?

Tags: category-theory, type-theory

The category of relations between sets has an internal hom (Cartesian product).

You have an isomorphism

$$ \textbf{Rel}(A, B \times C) \sim \textbf{Rel}(A \times B, C) $$

However, Rel is closed monoidal not closed Cartesian (there is a Cartesian product/coproduct structure of the disjoint union of sets but it doesn't work together properly with the Cartesian product of sets.)

Anyhow this means you can compile a linear lambda calculus to the category of relations.

But if Cartesian product becomes some sort of linear function type in the internal language of Rel what do functions become?

I know you can define functions without mentioning Set by defining functions to be relations with exactly one output for all inputs. But I'm not sure what this means as an object in category theory or how this would translate to type theory.

A direct translation of defining function types as total relations might be something like

$$
\frac{\begin{split}\Gamma \vdash E \colon A \times B 
\\ \Gamma \vdash E' \colon B \times A
\\ \Gamma, x\colon B \vdash p \colon E \, (E' \, x) \sim x
\\ \Gamma, y\colon A \vdash q \colon E' \, (E \, y) \sim y\end{split}}{\Gamma \vdash \textbf{mkfn}(E, E', x. p, y. q) \colon A \rightarrow B}
$$

A function is defined a pair of relations and witnesses of identities.

It's probably possible to make sense of this somehow. I've been trying to figure out simpler variations on this idea myself. But the whole matter edges way too close to the complexity of dependent types for my liking. And some issues such as handling the typing environment seem really fiddly.

I hope this clarifies why it's not quite so simple to define a function type the way I'm thinking of the issue as the most straightforward definitions would drag in the weirdness of witnesses of identity types.

Is there a simpler solution to this sort of mess?

Comment: Do you know how to construct the functor $\textbf{Set} \to \textbf{Rel}$? The functional relations in $\textbf{Rel}$ are those 1-cells which are left-adjoints. Also see the 2-categorical version using $\textbf{Cat}$ and $\textbf{Prof}$.

Comment: @vikraman I'm not quite sure I get you but given adjoint relations p, q, $\text{id} \Rightarrow q \circ p$ and  $p \circ q \Rightarrow \text{id}$ the left adjoint is functional. I can think of a few ways to map this to introduction/elimination rules although it's kind of odd.

Comment: @vikraman I've added a little explanation as to why a straightforward interpretation of that kind of definition within type theory is a little awkward.

Comment: There's some programming language whose terms denote elements of the power object, i.e. subtypes, but I can't recall what it's called or keywords to search for. In any case, perhaps something can be done for relations in a topos corresponding to morphisms $X\to PY$,

Comment: @VladimirSotirov Yes. It seems to me you want some sort of internal notion of subobject in Rel something like $\{ R \colon A \otimes B \mid \forall x, R (R^{\textbf{T}} x)\sqsubseteq x \}$ but I doubt Rel has a straightforward notion of object classifier. You probably want a weaker notion than the usual subobject classifier. It's definitely unclear to me how to internalize subobjects in Rel.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov So Coq has Prop but IIRC it isn't quite a subobject classifier. For a start you need to assume propositional extensionality as an axiom I think. Avoiding such issues is one of my motivations. My hope is if you can reason internal to Rel you can avoid ever mentioning a subobject classifier and even work with categories that lack classifiers entirely. I'm partly inspired by categories with proarrow equipment. Really classifiers and relations are the same thing just one is the same view but from the "side."